# Question about application of Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have seen the following version of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for $p>2,$
$$\forall v \in H^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right), \quad \int|v|^{p+1} \leq C\left(\int|\nabla v|^{2}\right)^{\frac{d}{4}(p-1)}\left(\int|v|^{2}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{4}(2-d)(p-1)}.$$
I want to know if the following inequality is valid:
$$|| v^p||_{L^2}\leq C||v||^{p}_{H^1}.$$
I tried to use the above inequality by replacing $p+1$ by $2p$ and this gave me,
$$||v^p||_{L^2}\leq C ||\nabla v ||_{L^2}^{\frac{d}{2}(p-1)} ||v||_{L^2}^{1+\frac{1}{2}(2-d)(p-1)}$$
and then I used the fact that $||v||_{L^2}\leq ||v||_{H^1}$ and $||\nabla v||_{L^2}\leq ||v||_{H^1}$ to get that,
$$||v^p||_{L^2}\leq C ||v ||_{H^1}^{\frac{d}{2}(p-1) + 1+\frac{1}{2}(2-d)(p-1)} = C ||v||_{H^1}^{p}.$$
Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\||v|^p\|_{L^2} = \|v\|_{L^{2p}}^p$, you are essentially asking whether $H^1 \hookrightarrow L^{2p}$. That is true if and only if $$
\begin{cases}
2p \leq \infty, & d = 1, \\
2p < \infty, & d = 2, \\
2p \leq \frac{2d}{d-2}, & d \geq 3,
\end{cases}$$

see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality).

**Edit:** Regarding your argument, I do not think that your “version of the Gagliardo--Nirenberg inequaltiy” is correct. In particular, I do not think it holds for $p+1 > \frac{2d}{(d-2)_+}$. Your calculation then seems in general correct, although I believe that the exponents are wrong: You have not replaced $p+1$ by $2p$ in all places, do you?